# I want to compare the input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a dynamic table with addon button which has three inputs, I want to compare that the first input value is not greater than the second input and Third input value is not greater than First and Second..please help me to solve this out...

```html
<table id="myTable" class="form-group" cellpadding="10" table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='from[]' onkeyup='compare();' placeholder='From'id='first'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='to[]' onkeyup='compare();' placeholder='To' id='second'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='gap[]' onkeyup='compare();' placeholder='Gap' id='third'></td>

    </tbody>

</table>
<center>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">+Addmore</button>
<br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>

</center>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(e){
  document.getElementById('myForm').action=`/create/${e.value}`;
  document.getElementById('pro').value=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='From' name='from[]'>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='To'  name='to[]'>";
  cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='Gap'name='gap[]'>";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var first=document.getElementById('first').value;
var second=document.getElementById('second').value;

if(parseInt(first)&lt;parseInt(second))
alert('Second Value is Greater than first');

else if(parseInt(first)&gt;parseInt(second))
alert('First Value is Greater than second');

else if(parseInt(first)==parseInt(second))
alert('First Value and second value is equal');
</script>
```

Comment: First off, your code does not have funciton `compare()`. Then, `keyup` is probably not the ideal event to check - I'd do that on `blur`. Next, you cannot use HTML entities in Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i also want that when these conditions are not true Submit button are disable... when true Submit button are not disable

Better to add `id="button"` to the button to shortly get it. This code works:

```
function compare() {
    if(parseInt(first.value) < parseInt(second.value)) {
        alert('Second Value is Greater than first');
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }

    else if(parseInt(first.value) > parseInt(second.value)) {
        alert('First Value is Greater than second');
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }

    else if(parseInt(first.value) == parseInt(second.value)) {
        alert('First Value and second value is equal');
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }

    else button.disabled = "true";
}
```

Also we can hide it instead of blocking.

Comment: When i edit something pop up comes and Button is not disable

Comment: I want if (conditions are true= button is enables )

Comment: if condition were false button was enabled

Comment: You mean if they == then enabled, if > or < -  disabled?

Comment: If all conditions are true then Button are clickable

Comment: if condition is not true then button is enabled

Comment: You closed to ans my question

Comment: "Else if" will work only if previous conditions are false. So all conditions can't be true. Only one condition may be true.

Comment: Oh. Seems that you want to inverse: if one of conditions is true - the button is disabled, if no one - enabled. Right?

Comment: "If pop up was in screen" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: It's Done bro I do it with your Help thnx for that it's really appreciable  thnx buddy

Answer (score 1):

Need to put the checking code into the "compare" function and use correct comparison signs (<>). This works:

```
function compare() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;

    if(parseInt(first) < parseInt(second))
    alert('Second Value is Greater than first');

    else if(parseInt(first) > parseInt(second))
    alert('First Value is Greater than second');

    else if(parseInt(first) == parseInt(second))
    alert('First Value and second value is equal');
}
```

Also you can get elements just by their id (if no variables with such names), so the next code is shorter but also works:

```
function compare() {
    if(parseInt(first.value) < parseInt(second.value))
    alert('Second Value is Greater than first');

    else if(parseInt(first.value) > parseInt(second.value))
    alert('First Value is Greater than second');

    else if(parseInt(first.value) == parseInt(second.value))
    alert('First Value and second value is equal');
}
```

Comment: Thnx for your intention but i also want that when these conditions are not true Submit button are disable... when true Submit button are not disable

Comment: You can create a new question and I will answer there.

Comment: But it is not my -1. Probably the person, who commented the question above, made -1.

Comment: Ok i write a new question then

Comment: Ok. I can put the solution as the second answer.

Comment: I see that I can't mark several answers with green tick too. New tick removes previous one. But I have seen one question with two green ticks. Strange.

Comment: I don't like Android, iOS where too many limits and need root etc. Windows without limits is the best.

Comment: Why? You can disable hidden reporting. Or you mean viruses?